# Detect if Xcode is currently building

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I want to track the time I am waiting for Xcode to be ready in a typical workday. From pressing "Run" to seeing the app on my sim/iphone screen. Is there a way to detect if Xcode is currently building/linking/copying something? 
At the moment I just do a glorified version of

> ps ax | grep "/clang"

Is there a better way to do this? I looked into the scripting bridge header of Xcode but I could not find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add two "Run Script" build phases to your Xcode project which runs a tiny script. One at the beginning and at the end of building.

The script at the beginning could literally be something like

```
#!/bin/sh

date=`date`
# this echo puts the line into your Build Log
echo "time started building is $date"
# and doing a "cat" into some file will save it
cat "time started building is $date" > /path/to/your/buildlog.txt
```

and the same thing at the end.

You can also do "Pre-Action" and "Post-Action" methods in your Build scheme.  They might look like this:

[image]

Only here, you'd do the appropriate script thing.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a reliable option. The only problem I see is that I would have to add this to Run/Test/Archive on every scheme. It would be nice if I could somehow avoid this.